# Can I target multiple divs (with the same class) to escape HTML special entities with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, htmldecode

My Webflow search results page is rendering html special entities, which I need to render as html.

My current javascript takes the content of the first search result, decodes it, & places that code into all subsequent search results (divs with the class "html-conversion"). Instead, I need it to individually decode each search result.

```
// Function that unespaces HTML
function htmlDecode(input){
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;
    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

// Store value of html into variable
var code = $(".html-conversion").html();

// Store unescaped value into new variable
var formattedCode = htmlDecode(code);

// Place new value back into the embed
$(".html-conversion").html(formattedCode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cycle, to replace all - instead of identify one particular

```
  $( "html-conversion" ).each(function() {
    var code = $(this).html();
    var formattedCode = htmlDecode(code);
    $(this).html(formattedCode);
  });
```

or if you need identify one particular and you have a way get index of element than try `$( "html-conversion:eq( indexhere )" )`

Comment: Awesome! This code is missing a closing parenthesis, but was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: oh, Im sorry man about missing ```);```, edited to be right :)